# How to enable external user sign in in SharePoint 2019 On prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to share documents with external users on SP 2019. We have tried anonymous access but we want the external users to sign in using their personal email IDs and then access the documents

Answer (score 1):

Referring to another [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfe7b3e2-86df-4280-8977-14f592c485cf/sharepoint-on-premise-with-external-users-authentication-via-microsoft-live-id?forum=SP2019) with similar request:

SharePoint 2019 cannot communicate directly with Live ID. The current alternative provided by Microsoft is **Azure Active Directory** (which you can invite external users to).

Please see the detailed information here:
[Tutorial: Azure Active Directory single sign-on (SSO) integration with SharePoint on-premises.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial)